# Neo4j LOAD CSV retrieving no changes,no records

Tags: neo4j

I am working on a small project where I am storing the data in neo4j database. I want to import data from a csv and also create a relation with another type of nodes.

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///sample.csv' AS line
CREATE (product:Product { productId:line.ProductID,
name: line.Item_Name,
desc:line.Item_Description})
WITH product MATCH(i:Image) where i.imageId in line.listofvals
Create(product)-[:hasImage]->(i);
```

This query is not Working

Note:The line.listofvals contains the list of elements

The below query is working when used without LOAD csv

```
CREATE (product:Product { productId:1,
name: "name",
desc:"desc"})
WITH product MATCH(i:Image) where i.imageId in [100,101]
Create(product)-[:hasImage]->(i);
```

But when I use LOAD CSV I am unable to execute the same query. Can anyone help me with this.

Comment: What you mean `not working` and `unable to execute`? Some errors? And show an example of data from the csv file, together with the headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't tell Cypher that `line.listOfVals` should be a collection.

So let's assume that the value is a list of ids separated by `|` :

1. Cypher will consider this value as a string
2. You need to split it and convert string ids to integers

Simple example :

```
WITH "123| 456| 789 " AS listOfVals
RETURN extract(x IN split(listOfVals, "|") | toInt(trim(x)) ) AS vals
```

-

```
╒═════════════╕
│"vals"       │
╞═════════════╡
│[123,456,789]│
└─────────────┘
```

Making your LOAD CSV query having to look like :

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///sample.csv' AS line
CREATE (product:Product { productId:line.ProductID,
name: line.Item_Name,
desc:line.Item_Description})
WITH product, 
     extract( x IN split(line.listofvals, "|") | toInt(trim(x)) ) AS vals
MATCH(i:Image) where i.imageId IN vals
Create(product)-[:hasImage]->(i);
```

Comment: It worked and successfully inserted the nodes in the database. Thanks a ton